# How to loot sea monsters in The Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

By sea monsters I mean all the monsters killed in waters. How do I loot from their remains as it doesn't come out for collecting stuff. I even tried killing some on my boat, but it just doesn't happen. There are so many Sirens and Erynias flying around over open waters, so much of shell farming goes to waste. Anyways anyone have a clue how to loot in such scenarios?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Dallium seems to be correct in that critters that die underwater due to crossbow shots don't seem to drop loot.  Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be what you're asking.

If you kill something **over** the water, (siren or other hybrid while on a boat) their body will drop to the surface of the water and float while their loot drops to the bottom.  When the battle is over, dive in & swim down to collect your lovely, lovely loot.  If you are over deep enough water, take a swig of Killer Whale before diving to extend your ability to hold your breath.

Of course, even on land, some of the critters you kill with your sword just don't drop any loot.  This happens on boats too.

It seems to make a difference if you slay them "on the wing" vs. knocking them into the water & delivering the killing blow as they float next to your boat.  I've not seen a stunned + floating + death blow opponent leave loot.

### Edit

A recent patch seems to have reduced the vertical range at which loot is shown on the mini-map.  It now seems as if you need to dive to detect loot if the water is more than a few fathoms deep.

Comment: I had never checked at the deeps of water, in shallow places the witcher sense won't show anything though, but anyways I'll try looking for it

Comment: @SwapnilRastogi, If the mini-map shows a loot icon, then it's worth looking.  Otherwise don't bother.  I play on PC and the loot glows a nice yellow under Witcher Sense.  It just took me a while to look *below* the corpse...

Comment: Oh yeah that's another issue, I don't see the red X mark for loot drop. Also is there no way you get loot after killing with crossbow? Coz killing Sirens and Erynias over water with a sword is hard

Comment: @SwapnilRastogi I've never gotten a drop from something I've killed with a crossbow while swimming, though swimming does seem to supercharge the killing power of your crossbow.  Killing those things on a boat is really not much different than doing it on land.  Use Hybrid Oil on your Silver Sword.  Stand waiting for them to swoop.  Time it so that you're the one who get's the blow in.  The difference is the damned sail blocking much of your view....

Answer (score 5):

I think you're asking how to loot the corpses of monsters who die in water. If that's what you're asking, **you can't loot monsters who die in water.**